# UI Bootstrap datepicker duplicated when appended to body

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm using `ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup` in a filter header template inside `ui.grid`. This lets me filter rows by date. I also have a button inside the grid menu that toggles `grid.options.enableFiltering`.

Due to alignment issues with `ui-grid`, I have `datepicker-append-to-body` set to true for my datepickers. The first time I enable filtering, everything works fine. However, when I disable filtering and re-enable it, I get duplicate datepickers.

**This is what the problem looks like:**
[image]

I think the problem is that each time the filters are enabled, the following `div` is appended to the DOM and never removed when the filters are disabled.

```html
<div uib-datepicker-popup-wrap=""
     ng-model="date"
     ng-change="dateSelection(date)"
     template-url="uib/template/datepickerPopup/popup.html"
     class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid-date-disabled"
>
    <!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
</div>
```

**Here's a simplified plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/eYZt87j2O6A5xhjHj5ZG
I get the same issue if I only use one datepicker inside the `Time Range` filter header.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: This is wiered. When you toggle filter options, It keep on adding 2 datepicker in body each time.. I did toggle filter option of grid 4 times and I saw 8 uib-datepicker in DOM got added. Also other interesting question is, Why It shows only 2 datepicker a when you open filter :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an answer on why this is happening but a solution without jQuery would be to remove the pop-up when triggering the filter toggle using document.querySelectorAll()

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div[uib-datepicker-popup-wrap]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(node) {
     node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/poYzR6oJJIttXmCTu11Z?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution is a fine workaround, thank you! For anyone reading this in the future, you can throw this in the `$onInit` of a directive on a `span` wrapping the `.ui-grid-filter-container` to make it a bit cleaner.